# PL/SQL REPLACE STATEMENT

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

```
SQL_STMT := 'UPDATE KTK SET New_Phone_Number = REPLACE(Phone_Number, '.','-')';
```

It has compile error.
`PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "." when expecting one of the following:     * & = - + ; < / >` at in is mod remainder not rem     <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2    like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset The symbol "* was inserted before "." to continue.

what am I missing?

but

```
UPDATE KTK 
SET New_Phone_Number = REPLACE(Phone_Number, '.','-')
```

is working well in SQL developer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to double escape strings in dynamic sql in oracle. If not the sql string will look like it ends at the first single quote.

Try something like:

```
'UPDATE KTK SET New_Phone_Number = REPLACE(Phone_Number, ''.'',''-'')';
```

Comment: I think you've got too many quotes there. You only need two at each point rather than three.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to escaping the quotes, as suggested by Logard, I quite like the quote literal added in Oracle 10g.

The format for your statement would be:

```
SQL_STMT := q'{UPDATE KTK SET New_Phone_Number = REPLACE(Phone_Number, '.','-')}';
```

This text literal format is documented in the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218)